# How do i convert bigint to int in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I wanted to find out negative values in one of the columns of type bigint. 
so when i do select *from tablename where columname(bigint) <0 ... its throwing me an error.

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint[] < integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 60
  ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint[] < integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 60
```

The table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE oper.asset_input_event 
(
  id                   bigserial NOT NULL,
  trip_ids             bigint[],
  cassandra_uuid       uuid,
  asset_id             integer,
  zbox_input_id        integer,
  org_gps_id           integer,
  gpssn                bigint,
  input_state          boolean,
  interrupt_code       characteR VARYING(25),
  start_geography_id   integer,
  end_geography_id     integer,
  is_cold_start        boolean,
);
```

And the query is:

```
SELECT trip_ids 
from oper.asset_input_event 
where trip_ids < 0
```

Comment: You might want to [read up on syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-expressions.html)

Comment: @Reaces: I agree with you, but please don't link to outdated versions. Use `current` instead of the `8.2` in the link

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What it the answer?? could u please help me?

Comment: i mean select *from tablename where columnname < 0... where column name is of type bigint.

Comment: here goes the table creation script. 
CREATE TABLE oper.asset_input_event
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  trip_ids bigint[],
  cassandra_uuid uuid,
  asset_id integer,
  zbox_input_id integer,
  org_gps_id integer,
  gpssn bigint,
  input_state boolean,
  interrupt_code character varying(25),
  start_geography_id integer,
  end_geography_id integer,
  is_cold_start boolean,
  bbox geometry ) And the query : SELECT trip_ids from oper.asset_input_event where trip_ids < 0

Comment: Don't add code in comments. **edit** your question (I did this for your).

Answer (score 6):

Your column is not of type bigint it's an **array** of integers.

And if you read the error message carefully it tells you exactly that:

> operator does not exist: bigint[] < integer

It says that the `<` operator is not defined to compare an *array* of bigints against a single integer value.

I can only *guess* what you are trying to do. I assume you are looking for rows where at least *one* of the ids stored in that array is lower than 0.

When arrays are involved you need to use the `all` or `any` operator to compare against all values in the array. Unfortunately you can't write `any(trip_ids) < 0` so you need to invert the condition to:

```
SELECT trip_ids 
from oper.asset_input_event 
where 0 > all(trip_ids);
```

That will return all rows where all values in the `trip_ids` array are smaller than 0. If you want to find those where at least one is smaller than 0 you can use the `any` operator.

```
SELECT trip_ids 
from oper.asset_input_event 
where 0 > any(trip_ids);
```

---

Using an array usually indicates a bad data model. This should better be normalized to a proper 1:many relationship.

Comment: It worked...thanks alot... But i am not able to vote you as it needs 15 reputation.

Comment: @user1782548: You can [*accept* the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), though.